# How to select text between two string using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to select a text between two string from html like below:

```
<div class='detail'>
   Name: Seng ChandaraH/P: 012485472 & 010485472Email: chandara.seng@mdh.asia
</div>
```

How can I select only **Seng Chandara** text?

Here is my code

```
var data = $('.detail').text().match(/(?<=Name:)(.*)(?=H\/P)/);
```

console.log(data);

but it not work. when I use regex101.com and use this `(?<=Name:)(.*)(?=H\/P)` I can get the result i want, but I don't know how to use it in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a look-behind regex, which is not available using JavaScript. However, the lookahead is available:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead

One way to do it based on your code:

```
$('.detail').text().match(/Name.+(?=H\/P)/)[0].replace(/Name: /, '')
```